# Is org-depend.el discontinued?

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to make a TODO item dependent on another TODO item from a different heading and while searching for this feature, I stumbled upon org-depend.el.

From the official site docs it seems that I can do exactly that using the BLOCKER/ID properties, but my problem is that I can't seem to find org-depend.el and using (require 'org-depend) gives me a "cannot find file" error.

I have looked inside the org-mode repository and the file is not in the lisp folder. Is it dead?

Links:

[org-mode Repository](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode)

[org-depend Official Doc](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-depend.html)

Answer (score 2):

[org-depend.el](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib/tree/master/item/lisp/org-depend.el) along with other `org-contrib` add-ons have been forked off into a [separate repository](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib) since org-mode 9.5.

`org-contrib` can be installed as a package from the [NonGNU ELPA](https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/org-contrib.html) repository.

Answer (score 1):

It is in `contrib`: it is not officially supported but it is available e.g. from the [Org mode repository](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/contrib/lisp/org-depend.el) in the `contrib/lisp` subdirectory.

EDIT: The `contrib` directory has been moved to its own [repository](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib) where [ord-depend.el](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib/tree/master/item/lisp/org-depend.el) can now be found.

If you are interested and able, you can volunteer to adopt one or more of these orphaned packages. Instruction are in the [repository page](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ebzg/org-contrib).